# Mark a single Laravel notification as read

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page in my application that displays a list of all of the notifications a user currently has that are unread and each notification will have a read icon.

The ID in the database is set to `char` so is a long string of letters and numbers. When I display the id of the notifications on the page, they all return numbers that in no way relate to what is in the database so when I run a query to read a notification, it can't find the ID because the ID isn't matching.

What is the best method to read a single notification in Laravel? I'm using the code below to try, but it's the `$request->get('id')` that's incorrect as I seem to get 12310 as an ID and even 0 for some of them.

```
Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $request->get('id'))->markAsRead()
```

Comment: if you can provide some codes, others can help you better.

Comment: type cast them properly before doing any action

Comment: you meant to say the char data stored in database is not same as display ? Qn 1 : How the char data stored in db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel `notifications` table's `id` use `CHAR` as the default field type. So, when you filter for certain id you have to use `first()` like the following. Since the `unreadNotifications` is the `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection`

```
$notificationId = request('notification_id');

$userUnreadNotification = auth()->user()
                            ->unreadNotifications
                            ->where('id', $notificationId)
                            ->first();

if($userUnreadNotification) {
    $userUnreadNotification->markAsRead();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function above will return an array use first method :
$note = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $request->get('id'))->first()->get();
$note->markAsRead();

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `notifications` table's id uses CHAR as the default field type. So, when you filter for a certain id you have to use `first()` like the following.

My `xxx.blade.php`is:

```
 

   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications<span class="badge">{{ count(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications) }}</span>

        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            @foreach(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
            <a href="{{route('vendor.commentReplay',[ 'id' => $notification->id])}}" class="dropdown-item" >
                {{$notification->data['user']['email']}} commented on <strong> {{$notification->data['CommentDetails']['comment']}}</strong>
            </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </li>
```

In `web.php`:

```
    Route::get('comment-replay/{id}','VendorsController@comment_replay')->name('commentReplay');
```

and Finally in my `VendorsController@comment_replay` function is like below:

```
    public function comment_replay($id)
    {
        $userUnreadNotification = auth()->user()
                                        ->unreadNotifications
                                        ->where('id', $id)
                                        ->first();
    
        if($userUnreadNotification) {
            $userUnreadNotification->markAsRead();
        }
    }
```